# Mysql select query NOT IN in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called products with 3 columns. One of the column is product_id. This column contains duplicate product ids. From another source I was getting some other product ids. I want to display the not existing product ids count . For example I am getting product ids 12,13,14,15,16 from one source. In my products table I am having 12,13,14. So now I want to display the count of not existing product ids . In this case that should be 2. To achieve that I tried with below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) 
FROM products p1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) 
     FROM products p2 
     WHERE p2.product_id IN (12,13,14,15,16) AND p1.product_id = p2.product_id)
```

But I am getting empty result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By reading your question it is so confusing, can you split in a parts so that all can understand what you are facing and what kind of help you required

Comment: Do the values `(12,13,14,15,16)` come from an application or another table?

Comment: Do you mean `...left join... using (product_id) where p2.product_id is null and...`?

Comment: *"For example I am getting product ids 12,13,14,15,16 from one source"* What a source? You have hardcoded this withing SQL.

Comment: Yes, I am getting those ids dynamically from other table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list of products comes from an application, and you know the length of the list as well (in this case 5) you can find the number of non-existent products in the table like this:

```
SELECT 5 - COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) AS non_existent_products
FROM products
WHERE product_id IN (12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
```

Output

```
non_existent_products
2
```

If you don't know the length of the list, you can figure it out using e.g.

```
LENGTH('(12, 13, 14, 15, 16)') - LENGTH(REPLACE('(12, 13, 14, 15, 16)', ',', '')) + 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11d0bcb4aa6259048e389e60ae603256)

**Update**

If the other `product_id` values are coming from another query (e.g. `SELECT product_id FROM othertable`) you can find the count of products in that result that are not in the `products` table using a `LEFT JOIN` of the results from that query with the products table and taking the difference in `COUNT`s of `product_id` from the two. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT q.product_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS non_existent_products
FROM (SELECT product_id FROM products2) q
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id = q.product_id
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9eea707ce39820d9e7d020fdf036683e)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, we have 2 tables having the following values:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`)
             VALUES    (1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(3),(1),(2),(5)
;

INSERT INTO `other_products` (`product_id`)
             VALUES    (2),(4)
;
```

Then this query gives you the count of each id 1, 3 and 5 (not existing in `other_products`)

```
SELECT `p`.`product_id`, COUNT(`p`.`product_id`) `count`
  FROM       `products`        `p`
  LEFT JOIN  `other_products`  `o`
  USING      (`product_id`)
  WHERE `o`.`product_id` IS NULL
  GROUP BY `p`.`product_id`
;
```

while this one gives you the total distinct ids not existing in the other table

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `p`.`product_id`)
  FROM       `products`        `p`
  LEFT JOIN  `other_products`  `o`
  USING      (`product_id`)
  WHERE `o`.`product_id` IS NULL
;
```

See [Live Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36Jhvrvk9rv6qWnGDZiJFS/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
select count(A.product_id) from (select distinct product_id from product where product_id not in (1,2)) AS A;
```

here you are selecting distinct product_id from table product where product id's are not equals to 1 and 2 then creating an alias for the result as A.

A acts as temporary table, so you need to use A.product_id to select.

Sorry for the bad english, but it i hope it meets requirement of question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having it's that your sub query always returns a value (some times returns 0) so when you do NOT EXISTS () it's allways FALSE, because you allways get an answer.
You should change NOT EXISTS by 0> like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) 
FROM products p1 
WHERE 0>
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) 
     FROM products p2 
     WHERE p2.product_id IN (12,13,14,15,16) AND p1.product_id = p2.product_id)
```